# Create a custom DNS error page

Tags: google-chrome-extension, overriding, custom-error-pages

I am building a new extension and I would like to customize the default error page in Google Chrome. I have gone through the "Override Pages" documentation [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/override.html) but have yet to find anything about customizing the page I have specified.

Any suggestions are much appreciated. Thank you.

The error page I want to customize is:

> This webpage is not available
>
> The server at ***_*___** can't be found, because the DNS lookup
>   failed. DNS is the network service that translates a website's name to
>   its Internet address. This error is most often caused by having no
>   connection to the Internet or a misconfigured network. It can also be
>   caused by an unresponsive DNS server or a firewall preventing Google
>   Chrome from accessing the network. Here are some suggestions: Reload
>   this webpage later. Check your Internet connection. Restart any
>   router, modem, or other network devices you may be using. Check your
>   DNS settings. Contact your network administrator if you're not sure
>   what this means. Try disabling network prediction by following these
>   steps: Go to the wrench menu > Options > Under the Hood and deselect
>   "Predict network actions to improve page load performance." If this
>   does not resolve the issue, we recommend selecting this option again
>   for improved performance. Add Google Chrome as a permitted program in
>   your firewall's or antivirus software's settings. If it is already a
>   permitted program, try deleting it from the list of permitted programs
>   and adding it again. If you use a proxy server, check your proxy
>   settings or contact your network administrator to make sure the proxy
>   server is working. If you don't believe you should be using a proxy
>   server, adjust your proxy settings: Go to the wrench menu > Options >
>   Under the Hood > Change proxy settings... > LAN Settings and deselect
>   the "Use a proxy server for your LAN" checkbox.
>
> Error 105 (net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED): Unable to resolve the server's
>   DNS address.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `chrome.override` isn't meant for this. Instead you can detect a DNS resolution error using [chrome.webRequest API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html). If you see this error you can load a different URL into the tab. Something along these lines:

```js
chrome.webRequest.onErrorOccurred.addListener(onErrorOccurred, {urls: ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]});

function onErrorOccurred(details)
{
  if (details.error == "net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED")
    chrome.tabs.update(details.tabId, {url: "..."});
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am developing an extension needs to hook this error. I never know this method before you point it out.

Comment: @wukong what is the extension name?