# Finding previous URL from window.history

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser-history

I've [hosts file blocking](http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hosts.htm) so time to time, I get these "Page not found" errors browsing thru deals.

Since I got tired of copying the target url, unescaping, replacing it in address bar and hitting enter, I wrote a handy bookmarklet to automate this:

```
(function () {
    var href = window.location.href;
    var loc = href.indexOf('url=');
    if (loc > 0) {
        var endLoc = href.indexOf('&', loc + 4);
        endLoc = endLoc > 0 ? endLoc : href.length;
        window.location.href = unescape(href.substring(loc + 4, endLoc));
    }
})()
```

Now the problem is that Chrome, internally redirects and unreachable page to its own `bounce.php` which produces the following error page.

[image: Screenshot]

Since it supports [history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.history) API, the URL in browser address bar doesn't change, as evident from the following data:

```
> JSON.stringify(window.history)  
{"state":null,"length":2}
```

Now the problem is, my bookmarklet doesn't work since `window.location.href` points to `"data:text/html,chromewebdata"` once this happens.

I've looked at this question [How do you get the previous url in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528324/how-do-you-get-the-previous-url-in-javascript) whose accepted answer is blissfully incorrect. Rightfully so, `document.referrer` is empty in my case.

So is there a way to find the previous URL from `window.history`? `window.history.previous` is non-standard and doesn't work on Chrome anyway.

Comment: Have you considered creating a Chrome extension instead of using a bookmarklet?

Comment: Was thinking the same, although not sure if I'd have anymore access via that...

Comment: The [`chrome.webRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html) API can be used to detect network errors. For your specific use case, just monitor errors on `main_frame`. Here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514883/create-a-custom-dns-error-page/8517197#8517197. Before trying to create a Chrome extension, have you already looked in the generated source of the error page? Are you sure that the original URL cannot be found in it?

Comment: Yep! Looked at that already. Besides, view source cannot be relied upon as that may not work for any and every site. `chrome.webRequest` sounds like feasible - only that I've to take the high road now... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way (at least while it lasts!)

Chrome sets the entire URL in `document.title`, so querying it is all that's needed. Here's the modified code if anyone's interested:

```
(function () {
    var href = document.title;
    var loc = href.lastIndexOf('http');
    if (loc > 0) {
        var endLoc = href.indexOf(' is not available', loc);
        endLoc = endLoc > 0 ? endLoc : href.length;
        window.location.href = unescape(unescape(href.substring(loc, endLoc)))
    }
})()
```

**Note**: The double `unescape` is needed for links coming via Google Ads.