# Getting previous page URL instead of current page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, get

I am trying to get the current page URL and parameters but JavaScript and jQuery are returning the previous page's URL.

I am currently using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            function getUrlParameter(sParam){
                var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
                var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
                    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
                        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
                        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) {
                            return sParameterName[1];
                        }
                    }
            } 

            var charid = getUrlParameter('id');
            var charname = getUrlParameter('name');
            console.log(charid);
            console.log(charname);
    });
```

Sometimes if I Reload/Refresh the page it will give me the current/correct URL.

EDIT: I set the links on the previous page with this code

```
$.getJSON(ip + 'list_query.php', function(data) {
        // data now contains array
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            var fl = data[i]['superhero_name'].slice(0,1);
            $("#" + fl).append("<a href='" + ip + "biography.html?id=" + data[i]['id'] + "&name=" + data[i]['superhero_name'] + "'>" + data[i]['superhero_name'] + "</a");
        }
        });
```

Comment: Can you be more specific on how to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @Ludovic have a hyperlink on the previous page the previous page that has it's href generated by a for loop and inserted as an attribute by jQuery. when I click the link i am taken to the page that has the code listed here but it gets the href from the previous page for some reason.

Comment: Ok i see, i'm trying to reproduce your problem with two page linked with each other, can you post some more code to show how you set your URL?

Comment: @Ludovic I added some code

Comment: I don't think the problem come from your previous page. What is on your current page before your JQuery code?

Comment: @Ludovic Also, the URL in the browser is correct but the output in the console is undefined. If I output the URL itself it comes out as the URL from the previous page

Comment: don't you override the URL previously on your code? something like `window.location.href="previousPage.html"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64827/discussion-between-ludovic-and-arcaderob).

Comment: cannot comment (not enough reputation), but this may help:
[Finding previous URL from window.history][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030074/finding-previous-url-from-window-history

Comment: @CharlSteynberg That is somewhat the opposite of my problem. say the first page is yahoo.com and the second page is google.com, when i check the url on the second page it is returning the first url for some reason

Comment: Since it will work if you refresh, it sounds to me like a caching issue. Have you tried adding the meta tags to force the browser not to cache the page, or does it consistently work in a different browser?

Answer (score 1):

are you looking for the `current page` URL, or the `previous page` URL, or, are there conditions involved?

For the `current page` URL, try:

```
console.log(window.location.href);
```

Unfortunately you cannot sniff the visitor's history, but if you want to track their history while browsing your domain, it is very easy to just set their current page aka: "window.location.href" in LocalStorage, and name the keys accordingly and hence create a list/index -- or even save it in cookie(s). The latter you can then use in PHP directly; whereas the former (LocalStorage) you can send to the server via XMLHTTpRequest.

If you are having this issue due to a javascript framework or plug-in, try to disable them temporarily and test to see if you get the same results in order to trace the root of the problem.

**Update**

Regarding Javascript frameworks, the following thread on GitHub may be useful with:
[window.location issues](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/207)

Comment: I am looking for the current URL but the console is outputting the previous pages URL for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple to get the current page's URL with vanilla JS.  Do it like this:

```js
alert(document.location.href);
```

Hope this helps!